# How can I normalise Greek fonts in Konversation?

Tags: fonts

[image]

Above you can see that Greek letters don't show correctly.

Comment: It works fine for me. What fonts are you using? What DE? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Also, better blur your IP address.